# What is the longest dagger in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whether unique or smithable, what is the longest dagger in Skyrim? I know it does not effect the reach of the blade and I'm not picky on damage (it's a dagger, best case scenario 30x damage).

It's just that I know some weapons are longer than others, though length and weight don't reflect on any combat aspects, I need the dagger that looks the longest.

I cannot find any chart detailing length, or picture of all daggers, scaled equally, to determine which is longest. The best I can do is drop them from my inventory and eyeball which looks longer. So far steel dagger wins. But anything will help at this point.

Comment: Just because none of you care doesn't mean it's not a valid question. I'm building character just for aesthetics and I couldn't find my answer any where else.

Comment: size doesn't matter, it's how you use it that matters ;D

Comment: I suspect that the actual weapon model may differ, but that all daggers are probably the same length for hit collision detection.

Comment: They are; the best way to get an authoritative answer for this is probably going to be to crack open the .nif files for the daggers and measure the longest axes of the geometry bounding boxes (and also account for any scale factors the weapon data can apply, although I don't recall that being a thing.)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the blade of woe, from the dark brotherhood. Possibly a tie between that and a daedric dagger, which is very similar looking. Unless something in dragonborn dlc tops it.

EDIT: Blade of Woe is indeed longer than the Dragon Priest Dagger. I was wrong about the Daedric Dagger, shorter than either.
[image]

Comment: Can you prove any of this? Seems like you're just guessing.

Comment: Not so much guessing as drawing on old memories. And remembering being very impressed with how big the Blade is. But now I have proof! ;-)

Comment: Was this picture taken still, or while moving, it moves your weapons and thus heightening/shortening the view rendering it longer/shorter.

Comment: Standing still.

Comment: Ooooo damn. @CrusaderJ Well done.